# Easy-to-use, hosted web-shop with the ability to accept credit card payments

Tags: web-hosting

I'm looking for an easy-to-use web-shop, with the ability to pay by credit-card. Can you recommend any providers?

I've not yet researched this myself, and I've never dealt with credit card payments, so any and all advice on that subject is welcome.

P.S.: I am a full-time web-developer, so don't be afraid to get technical.

Comment: What country are you in? This will affect the merchant account solutions available to you.

Comment: DK - Denmark. But with international customers.

Comment: I'm a developer at http://www.solidshops.com and would recommend going the hosted route. It's easy to use and we focus on web designers that know HTML and CSS just like you. Credit cards, paypal and the like can be accepted by plugging in your account info.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is limited by country (it might be), but have you seen Shopify? It is a hosted webshop that I've heard tons of good things about. It seems to be very flexible.

https://www.shopify.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [Wazala](http://www.wazala.com/). It's very easy to set up and by default is intended to be used in a sort of "lightbox" interface, so there's minimal work required to even integrated it with an existing site. It *can* also be accessed as a page, if that's desired instead.